# vbscript selecting child nodes

Tags: xml, loops, vbscript

I have the following XML, `gXML` passed from a page to another page that sends an email.

```
<root>
   <Lease>
       <row hello="none@nowhere.com">
       <row hello="none@nowhere.com">
       <row hello="none@nowhere.com">
       <row hello="none@nowhere.com">
   </Lease>
</root>
```

I want to be able to send an email to each rows, I want it to be like this:

```vb
for (each row){
    blah blah blah (send email function)
}
```

How do I select rows in XML.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using VBScript I assume you have access to System.Xml.

Have a look on this page:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.childnodes.aspx

And dig around a bit more on Google as well, in particular look at using System.Xml.XPath. There are plenty of examples out there.

This is a test method I wrote in a console app I use for testing. It is written in C# but the idea should help:

```
    private static void ExtractUserNodeFromUsersXml()
    {
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

        string xml = @"<data xmlns=''><users><user id='33' culture='en-gb' />
<user id='38 culture='en-gb' />
<user id='285'culture='en-gb' /></users></data>";



        xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);

        string userid = "38";

        XPathNavigator nav = xmlDoc.CreateNavigator();

        XPathNodeIterator userNodes = nav.Select("data/users/user[@id='" + userGuid + "']");

        while (userNodes.MoveNext())
        {
            if (userNodes.Current is IHasXmlNode)
            {
                XmlNode node = ((IHasXmlNode)userNodes.Current).GetNode();

                if (node != null)
                {
                    string culture = node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("culture").Value;

                    Console.WriteLine(node.OuterXml);
                    Console.WriteLine("Culture is " + culture);
                }
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("******");
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine(xmlDoc.OuterXml);
    }
```

It might be a bit of overkill for what you need but if you look online and use this code to play around then it'll help. In fact I'll go and alter this method for your XML now.

Change the XPathNavigator to be this with your XML.

```
XPathNodeIterator emailNodes = nav.Select("root/Lease/row");
```

Make sure your XML is valid and remember that the 'xpath' is case sensitive.

Answer (score 2):

The VBScript version (best used with the [Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms763742%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) handy):

```
  ' Assuming you have a string in gXML, I fake it here, please
  ' note the closing of the row nodes!
  Dim gXML : gXML = Join(Array( _
       "<root>" _
     , " <Lease>" _
     , "  <row hello=""none@nowhere.com""/>" _
     , "  <row hello=""none@nowhere.com""/>" _
     , "  <row hello=""none@nowhere.com""/>" _
     , "  <row hello=""none@nowhere.com""/>" _
     , " </Lease>" _
     , "</root>" _
  ), "")
  Dim oXML : Set oXML = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
  oXML.loadXml gXML
  If 0 = oXML.ParseError Then
     Dim ndlRow : Set ndlRow = oXML.selectNodes("/root/Lease/row")
     If 0 < ndlRow.length Then
        Dim nRow
        For nRow = 0 To (ndlRow.length - 1)
            WScript.Echo nRow, "send mail to", ndlRow(nRow).getAttribute("hello")
        Next
     Else
        WScript.Echo "no rows found"
     End If
  Else
     WScript.Echo oXML.parseError.reason
  End If
```

output:

```
0 send mail to none@nowhere.com
1 send mail to none@nowhere.com
2 send mail to none@nowhere.com
3 send mail to none@nowhere.com
```

Instead of the counted loop

```
For nRow = 0 To (ndlRow.length - 1)
    WScript.Echo nRow, "send mail to", ndlRow(nRow).getAttribute("hello")
Next
```

you may use a For Each Loop:

```
Dim ndRow
For Each ndRow In ndlRow
    WScript.Echo "send mail to", ndRow.getAttribute("hello")
Next
```